# Disable linux user authentication except through ldap

Tags: linux, server, ldap, devops

For example I have one user named `user1` on my linux server, with password `p1`. Then I set up a ldap server and add user1 with password `p2`. Turns out now I can login as user1 with both `p1` and `p2`. How can I disable `p1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`passwd -l user`

That will lock the user account as you are using LDAP authentication you not need user on server. And `passwd -u user` will undo this

Alternatively, you can accomplish the same thing by prepending a `!` to the user's password in `/etc/shadow` (this is all `passwd -l` does behind the scenes).